# How to find the $CDF$ of random variable $Z = max/min(X,Y)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Consider two independent random variables $\,X\sim F_X\,$ and $\,Y\sim F_Y.\;$
Find the $\,CDF\,$ of random variables $Z_1=\max(X,Y)\;$ and $\;Z_2=\min(X,Y)\;.$

It means that for every outcome $\,w\,$ we have $Z_1(w)=\max\big(X(w),Y(w)\big)\;,\;$ so $Z_1$ jumps between values of $\;X\;$ and $\;Y\,.\;$ Same reasoning applies to $\;Z_2=\min(X,Y)\,$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1. You want $P(Z_1 < z_1$ and $Z_2 < z_2)$
2. '$Z_1 < z_1$' is the same as '$X < z_1$ and $Y < z_1$' because maximum(X,Y) less than something is equivalent to saying both X and Y are less than that same thing.
3. '$Z_2 < z_2$' is the same as '$X < z_2$ or $Y < z_2$' because minimum(X,Y) less than something is equivalent to saying X or Y is less than that same thing.
4. 'A and B and (C or D)' is the same as '(A and B and C) or (A and B and D)'
5. I think you might wanna take cases to see if $z_1 < z_2$ or $ > $ because we always have $Z_1 \ge Z_2$.
6. Oh right of course: '$Z_2 > z_2$' is the same as '$X > z_2$ and $Y > z_2$' because minimum(X,Y) greater than something is equivalent to saying both X and Y are greater than that same thing.